# First Order Nonlinear Recurrence Relation

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to solve the closed formula for $x_n$ given the first order non-linear recurrence relation below. Unlike linear recurrences with direct solutions, I can't find any good reference for non-linear recurrences especially of this form. Any help is appreciated.

$x_n = \frac{\theta}{\beta x_{n-1}}-1$ for $n > 1 $ and $x_1 = 1$. Both $\theta$ and $\beta$ are constants.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: You can solve instead the recurrence $Y_{n+1}=AY_n$, where $Y_n=\begin{pmatrix}p_n\\q_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}-\beta&\theta\\\beta&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$.

Comment: @fatherBrown big help. does this mean I can simultaneously solve $p_n$ and $q_n$? If so, that would be my solution to $x_n$.

$p_n = -\beta p_{n-1} + \theta q_{n-1}$ and $q_n = \beta q_{n-1}$

Comment: What are $\theta, \beta$? Are they any real numbers, or are there any constraints?

Comment: @Sil yup they're real numbers. No constraint for $\beta$ while $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$.

Comment: @user3183104 Yes, because the equation for $Y_n$ is linear with constant coefficients. The solution is $Y_n=A^{n-1}Y_1$. Notice that $A^{n-1}$ can be written in terms of the diagonalization of $A=P^{-1}DP$, as $A^{n-1}=P^{-1}D^{n-1}P$, when $A$ is diagonalizable, which is for most values of $\beta,\theta$, or the Jordan form in the rest of the cases.